# How do you retrieve the location of your mdb file and use it as a driver in c#

Tags: c#

Just began to code in VB.Net and I'm having difficulty on understanding how to get the location of the mdb file that I have.

I will use this file as my `app.config` and I have been using this mdb file to all my project in Vb.net.

I Vb.Net I use...

```
 dbCn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\projectname\bin\system_common.mdb"
```

What is the exact alternative in c#?

I tried doing...

```
//ComputerName/projectname/bin/system_common.mdb
```

But it does not work

Comment: Exactly the same in C#. `dbCn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\projectname\bin\system_common.mdb";`

Comment: @mjwills thank you! I have it correct now!